# Convert 'mm:ss' in to time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a string which contains a duration in minutes and seconds, as `'1302:47'`.

I want to store this in SQL Server and I chose the `time` data type.

How do I convert `'1302:47'` in to hrs:mins:secs to a `time` datatype?

I tried

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE('1302:40' AS time)

SELECT TRY_CONVERT(time, '1302:40')
```

and end up with NULL both times implying the conversion failed.

I am expecting 21:7:40 as in 21hrs, 7mins and 40seconds.

Should I use a different data type?

Should I convert it all to seconds and just store as an `int`?

Comment: Did you mean 40 seconds?

Comment: Yes. Edited to reflect.

Comment: the TIME datatype is for time on a clock, not duration. This could work, as long as you don't have a duration longer than 23:59:59. But keep in mind that a lot of data handling assumes that 21:7:40 means 7 minutes a 40 seconds after 9 PM, not a duration of 21 hours, 7 minutes, and 40 seconds.

Comment: ok, so what datatype should i use for storing duration like this?

Comment: 21.7 is not 21 hours and 7 mins... should be 21 hours and 42 mins

Comment: In most cases, I would recommend storing the number of seconds as an INT. It could then be formatted as needed for display at a later time if that's a concern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to split your string by ':' char, since that time in invalid. That's why you're getting a NULL value.

After that, you can try parse both the minutes and the seconds.

Finally, just add the minutes and seconds into a new empty time.

#### Example supporting the max of 23h:

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(20) = '1302:40';
DECLARE @min INT = ISNULL(TRY_PARSE(LEFT(@date,CHARINDEX(':',@date)-1) AS INT), 0);
DECLARE @sec INT = ISNULL(TRY_PARSE(RIGHT(@date,LEN(@date)-CHARINDEX(':',@date)) AS INT), 0);

DECLARE @time TIME = '00:00'
PRINT DATEADD(s, @sec, DATEADD(mi, @min, @time));
-- Outputs: 21:42:40.0000000
```

#### Example supporting more than 23h:

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(20) = '1302:47';
--DECLARE @date VARCHAR(20) = '3600:60';
DECLARE @min INT = ISNULL(TRY_PARSE(LEFT(@date,CHARINDEX(':',@date)-1) AS INT), 0);
DECLARE @sec INT = ISNULL(TRY_PARSE(RIGHT(@date,LEN(@date)-CHARINDEX(':',@date)) AS INT), 0);

DECLARE @time TIME = '0001-1-1 00:00'
IF @min < 1440
BEGIN
    PRINT CAST(DATEADD(s, @sec, DATEADD(mi, @min, @time)) AS VARCHAR(8));
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    IF @sec = 60
    BEGIN
        SET @sec = 0;
        SET @min = @min +1;
    END
    PRINT CONCAT(@min/60, ':', FORMAT(@min - (@min/60) * 60,'0#'), ':', FORMAT(@sec,'0#'))
END

-- Scenario #1. Given '1302:47', outputs: 21:42:47
-- Scenario #2. Given '3600:60', outputs: 60:01:00
```

Comment: It's close, but not quite ...
If you test this with '3600:60' you get 12:01:00 which is not correct. 
It should be 60:01

Comment: A day has 1440 minutes. If you want more than that you need a date - time is not enough because varies from 00:00 to 23:59:59

Comment: Here you go! Example with more than 23h. It outputs a VARCHAR